# Анимация сворачивания окна в Windows 7 и Delphi 7

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, windows-7, окно

Как известно, в Windows 7 при включённых эффектах окно сворачивается не мгновенно, а с анимацией длительностью в несколько сотых секунд.

У меня есть программа, написанная в Delphi 7, которая при нажатии на кнопку, сворачивает основное окно вызовом `Hide` и делает снимок экрана. Сейчас, чтобы избежать артефактов наподобие того, что на картинке ниже, перед снимком я добавил задержку в 2 секунды, чтобы окно успело спрятаться.

[image: Окно программы ещё видно]

Есть ли более правильное решение данной проблемы? Например, принудительно спрятать окно **мгновенно** или добавить проверку, что оно на 100% невидимо? Желательно, чтобы было работоспособно и в других версия ОС Windows.

Comment: а ты не пробовал отслеживать сообщение WM_SIZE  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size

Comment: Нашёл более простой способ.

Comment: Способ с AlphaBlend сомнительный, т.к потенциально. могут быть артефакты (например полупрозрачная рамка окна).

Comment: Наверно вы правы. В Windows XP (если кто-нибудь ею ещё пользуется), на месте формы остаётся белый прямоугольник: https://ibb.co/0y2SX5M Буду пробовать другие варианты.

Comment: @vlad-chapl Способ с сообщениями не работает. Во-первых, за появление/исчезание окна отвечает не WM_SIZE, а WM_SHOWWINDOW. А во-вторых, сообщение приходит **перед** тем, как окно начинает исчезать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл элегантное решение с использованием прозрачности (свойства `AlphaBlend` и `AlphaBlendValue`):

```
  DefaultTransparency := AlphaBlendValue;
  AlphaBlendValue := 0;
  AlphaBlend := True;
  try
    try
      MakeScreenshot;
    finally
      AlphaBlendValue := DefaultTransparency;
      AlphaBlend := False;
    end;
  except
  end;
```